# Which of these compact sets are possible such that they have the following measures?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, definite-integrals

I am supposed to construct compact sets $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ (if possible) that have the following properties:
lambda is the Lebesgue-measure:

$  \lambda (K^0) = \lambda (K)$. This is easy, just take $K=[-1,1]$

$ \lambda (K^0) < \lambda (K)$. I do not know whether such a set exists.

$ 0< \lambda (\partial K) = \lambda (K)$. Here, I am also not sure whether this construction is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find yourself some Cantor sets which have positive measure, and empty interior.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set

Comment: so, all 3 are correct, right?

Comment: Yes, they are all correct.

Comment: alright, but the other answer was wrong, right?

Comment: Yes, it was.  I deleted my comments about it, and they deleted their answer.